# Haskell Compiling Problem using GHCi Windows

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have developed a haskell application which is tested with **WinHugs** interpreter working fine .. when i try to comiple the same application using **WinGHCi** it prompts a error

```
   lexical error in string/character literal at character '\t'
```

I have used `\t` in **IO Program** to display text

Example :- `putStr "\n \n \t \t Hello ! "`

Any solutions ?

Comment: As I understand it, it's pretty hard to use an interpreter for compilation ;-)

Comment: i was using `GHCi` its a compiler r8 ? :-o

Comment: Strictly speaking, GHCi is an interpreter.  Don't mind me, I'm just playing with terminology.  As for your problem, it might help if you posted a minimum code snippet that displayed the issue.

Comment: Can you please post a minimal piece of code that produces your error? Thanks.

Comment: @FUZxxl i have a `IO Program` which print things eg : `putStr "\n \n \t \t Hello ! "` .. thats place where i get error .. other all modules compile file ~!

Comment: @TomMD my all modules compile fine except for the `IO Program` where i use `\t`

Comment: @Sudantha It works on my machine. It may be helpfull to paste the code into a pastebin of your choice and to give us the link.

Comment: @TomMD TeX is using an interpreter to compile your documents since ever ;)

Comment: @Fuzxxl - http://pastebin.com/9SzuBc3z

Comment: @Sudantha If you don't understand: FUZxxl is still asking for example code because what you have posted isn't even that much (it lacks any top level declaration).  Something like `module Main where ...  main = putStrLn "\t \t hi!"`  is a little closer.

Comment: actually im having the `main` module as a separate module in a another file !

Comment: @Sudantha Your code is completely strange. First, the definition of `menu` must not be indented and second a string must end on the same line, except if you're using a `\\` at the end of the line and a second one at the beginning of the next line to continue the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try this step-by-step guide:

1. Save your program in a file `program.hs` this file should contain a function `main` of the type `IO ()` that is executed at the program's start.
2. Open a shell in the directory where this file is.
3. Type `ghc -O3 --make program.hs` to compile `program.hs` into an executable `program.exe`.
4. Try to run `program.exe`

If the error still occurs, please post some more code to aid debugging.

Comment: Thanks FUZxxl i found the error was using space bar to keep spaces instead of `\t`